# codeigniter cookie not working in very basic controller

Tags: codeigniter

this is very simple codeigniter set cookie code which is not working. It is very basic form:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        set_cookie('apple','fruit');
        $cook = get_cookie('apple');
        print_r($cook);

    }
}
```

This is basically a test controller which does nothing but sets cookie. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The way you setting and retrieving is wrong.

---

**Setting cookie** is like this

```
$this->input->set_cookie();
```

**Retrieving cookie** is like this

```
$this->input->cookie();
```

[Check Cookie helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) and check this [example too](http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-set-cookie-in-codeigniter.html)

Comment: @vishwakarma09 happy to help :)

Comment: How do I make it expire never?

Comment: @vishwakarma09 in `application/config.php` Chnage `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;`